# How to complete this query to remove replication and then drop database?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I'm trying to remove replication and drop database all in one query when selecting the database from right-click context menu and running custom script.

I'm able to remove replication, but I get the error below when trying to drop database.

[image: error]

```
DECLARE @DB varchar(50)
SELECT @DB = DB_NAME()
USE master
EXEC sp_removedbreplication @DB
GO
DROP DATABASE @DB
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Product specific question.)

Comment: SSMS with a certain add-on (SSMS Tools Pack @ https://www.ssmstoolspack.com)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use a variable to specify the database to drop.
You need to use dynamic SQL for this, e.g.:

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max);
SET @sql = 'DROP DATABASE ' + QUOTENAME(@DB);
EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql;
```